# trying to get data from mysql in laravel 5 to show up

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5

I'm trying to get data from a table in my mysql database to show up using laravel 5.  FYI I'm using vagrant and have a windows host machine and CentOS is my guest machine.  I have data already in mysql table from importing the content of a text file.  Now I'm just trying to display that information within a view, but I'm getting this error `PDOException in Connector.php line 47:could not find driver`.  Now based off that error you could draw the conclusion that my database isn't connected to the laravel 5 project, but based off some of the detail of error it's reflecting the proper info in mysql.  It say's `at Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=BrightonCromwell', array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'BrightonCromwell', 'username' => 'root@localhost', 'password' => '', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql'), array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in MySqlConnector.php line 20`.  So It's calling the right column and reflecting the exact same information as mysql database's status.  So anyway this is what I have so far
In my Controller:

```
public function Lists()
{
    $fsc_lists = fscdata::all();
    return View('FSC_views.Lists', compact('fsc_lists'));
}
```

This is what i have in the view:

```
    @extends('layout.master')
    @section('content')
    <div class="figure"><img src="/Content/images/figure2.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="main">
        <h2>FSC List</h2>
        <ul>
            @foreach($fsc_lists as $fsc_list)
                <p>{{$fsc_list->fsc_number}}</p>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endsection
```

This is what I have in the .env file:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=BrightonCromwell
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=rootpassword
```

This is what I have in the database file:

```
<?php

return [
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
'default' => 'mysql',
'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

],

'migrations' => 'migrations',

'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],

];
```

This is what I have in migrations:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class FscDataTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('fscdata', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('fsc_number');
        $table->string('fsc_title');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('fscdata');
}

}
```

And this is what i have Under Apps:

```
<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class fscdata extends Model {
}
```

I followed the laracast videos to the best of my ability on this subject and just ran into a wall.  Please I need assistance, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion I already figured it out.  I needed to restart apache2 server, by typing in   `service httpd restart` in the root.  Thanks for the help though I'm sure that's another good way to go about it

Answer (score 0):

Install and enable the pdo_mysql extension.